# Fetch owners emailid using touchID iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, touch-id

Heard about apps registering using touchID.Is it possible to get the owners emailid using touchID? Or touchID is only used for authentication purposes or what?

What all datas are available through touchID in iOS?Can't find any proper docs about this.

Comment: No data is available via Touch ID. You can use TouchID to get a yes/no response; was a valid finger presented. You can also secure your own data in the keychain and require a TouchID to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Paulw11.So you are saying that iOS will not provide any of the owner data through touchid right?

Comment: That's correct. There is no way of accessing owner data. You can request access to contacts and the user's contacts may have their own details in there, but it is not guaranteed